# SQL Server Database Losing Primary Key after importing to ASP.NET Project

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am building a Website using ASP.NET MVC 4.5.

I am trying to import a database (oringal in .mdb) into the project.

What I did is:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, create a new database and import the data from  the mdb file.
2. Detach the database.
3. Copy mdf and ldf files to the desktop (Unable to add into App_Data when these files are in "Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA" even if I close SSMS and kill the "sqlservr.exe" process (it just keeps reopening).
4. Using "Add->Existing Item..." to add the mdf file into App_Data folders.

When I check with the server explorer and open the table definition, all the primary keys are gone.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: could you please explain why are you adding database file to project? When you detach database, cant you check drop connections?Are you shure that your import was success before detaching database?

Comment: I will avoid these words next time.

Comment: The database contains a number of record (more than 1000 rows) so I think I should use the existing database. Or is it a better approach to create a new database in the project and import the data? because i also need to include authentication in the website. I am sure the primary keys exist before detaching it.

Comment: so, what about losted primary keys, are you shure that you done correct export to mdb, and while your restore (import, step 1) primary key's were there?

Comment: the primary keys  lost when i was importing to SSMS (from mdb to mdf). and i manually add the primary keys in SSMS. I am sure i did save before detaching them.

Comment: Also, you don't need to keep your data in project files, keep it in DATA folder if you need local database.You are connected to database using connection string, you need sql server, only if you dont use sql compact.

Comment: I find this article https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=221&t=121696 , when primary key can be lost.It's related to the process of your export to .mdb, I think.

Comment: I will bet you used SSMS to add the PKs, and did not save them before closing the windows.  Next time, double-check the keys exist before doing the detach, always best to use TSQL.